# Inheritance of protected class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, protected

I have a doubt with this code ( it is a question into a test so I don't need to change ):

```
class X {
    protected:
    int v;
};

class Y : protected X {
public:
    Y() : v(0) {}
    
};

int main()
{
    Y *y = new Y();
    cout << y->v;
    delete y;
    return 0;
}
```

I was quite sure that it was good because the v member of X was accessible from Y because Y was the subclass of a protected Class which has a protected member ( v ) but I have a compilation error.
Can someone help me to understand? thanks!

Comment: "_...but I have a compilation error..."_ any errors should be in the question as formatted text.

Comment: `cout << y->v;` can only access `public` class members.

Comment: `Y` has acces to `v`

Comment: You aren't accessing the member from `Y`, you do it from `main()`.

Comment: Statements in `main()` cannot directly access `protected` members of your class.   `cout << y->v` attempts to do exactly that, so does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems.

The first one is that the class definitions

```
class X {
    protected:
    int v;
};

class Y : protected X {
public:
    Y() : v(0) {}
    
};
```

are ijll-formed. From the C++17 Standard( 15.6.2 Initializing bases and members ):

> 2 In a mem-initializer-id an initial unqualified identifier is looked
> up in the scope of the constructor’s class and, if not found in that
> scope, it is looked up in the scope containing the constructor’s
> definition. [ Note: If the constructor’s class contains a member with
> the same name as a direct or virtual base class of the class, a
> mem-initializer-id naming the member or base class and composed of a
> single identifier refers to the class member. A mem-initializer-id for
> the hidden base class may be specified using a qualified name. — end
> note ] **Unless the mem-initializer-id names the constructor’s class,
> a non-static data member of the constructor’s class, or a direct or
> virtual base of that class, the mem-initializer is ill-formed**.

That is you may not use the non-static member `v` of the base class `X` as an initializing member in the ctor initialization of the class `Y`:

```
Y() : v(0) {}
      ^^^^
```

The second problem is that as the data member `v` is protected in the derived class `Y` then you may not directly access it outside the class as you are doing

```
cout << y->v;
```

Either make the data member public or create a public member function that will return the value of the data member `v` or a constant reference to the data member.

Answer (score 3):

> I was quite sure that it was good because the v member of X was accessible from Y...

`Y` has access to `v`. In your code you attempt to access it from `main`.

You misunderstand what it means to declare a `protected` member. It is not a mechanism to turn something that cannot be accessed from outside in a base class into something that everybody can access in a derived class. It merely gives the derived class access:

```
class X {
    public:
    X(int v) : v(v) {}
    protected:
    int v;
};

class Y :  public X {
public:
    Y() : X(0) {         // Base class initializes its members 
        std::cout << v;  // OK
    }    
};
```

Moreover you seem to conflate `protected` inheritance with making a member `protected`, and I removed it from the above. It does not change the fact that `v` cannot be accessed from outside and I consider it beyond the scope of the question. You should read about both: protected members and protected inheritance.

---

PS: Do not use manual dynamic memory allocation by default. Your `main` should be

```
Y y;
cout << y.v;
```

And it would have the exact same issue. If you do need to dynamically allocate something, use smart pointers to manage the lifetime.